# Jenkins and github

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, jenkins

I have a jenkins server with the github plugin to trigger every time a change is made to the repo.
I have the private key and the public key loaded into the github repo.
The job is configured as:
Repository URL git@github.com:xxx/repo.git

I didn't enter the URL in the top part of the job.
One of the tasks I have Jenkins do is:
cd /var/www/html/ && git pull origin master
But whenever I make a change to the repo it is not being triggered and I don't know why.

When I run the build manually I get:
[Unit_Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1951363618156731736.sh
+ cd /var/www/html/
+ git pull origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
Sending email to: xx@xx.com
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I added eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/key_rsa which seems to have fixed the access issue but the build still isn't being triggered when a change is made.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use Jenkins as a shell script executor:

- Use the Git plugin and configure it correctly. With this you should be able to pull code
- Use the GitHub plugin and check the `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub` and add the hook to your repo on GitHub so Jenkins gets notified whenever a change is pushed
- Under the point `Pre Steps` add `Execute shell` and prepare the environment for the actual build

Comment: I did all that before. The issue was polling. I had to set that. It's working. For now :)

Comment: You don't need to use polling. If configured correctly, GitHub will notify your Jenkins installation when there's an update

Comment: Well, I was using a different test repo that worked without issue. The second one was configured correctly and I had to add the polling to get it to work.

Comment: Then what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Had to add polling with * * * * * to get it to work.

Comment: Checking every minute might be a bit excessive

Comment: There's no definite answer for that, maybe every 15 minutes? ``H/15 * * * *``